# String pool creating two string objects for same String in Java

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Strings and StringPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903094/java-strings-and-stringpool)

I created two Strings

```
String s1="MyString";
String s2=new String("MyString");
System.out.println(s1==s2);
```

it prints `"false"` . we know that String pool doesn't create two Objects for same String literal.

Then what is happening here? It's creating two different String Objects(literals) in String pool for same String literal "MyString".

I know  `equals()` method returns `true` here.

but when we use `==` it should compare two references  and they should refer to the same 
String Object in String constant pool.

Why It is not refering to the existing String object in the String pool even if it finds a match ?.

Comment: you are comparing object references (pointers) that are obviously not the same. Use String's `equal()` method to check object equality.

Comment: Yes! So what is your question exactly?

Comment: @Less i know the use of equal() but I am talking about "=="

Comment: If you use `new`, Java will _always_ create a new object.  Why are you surprised?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first one goes to the pool while the second one is stored on the heap.

Use `s2 = s2.intern();` to make it return `true`.

When you do an `intern()` on the string, the JVM ensures that the string is present in the pool. If it doesn't yet exist, it is created on the pool. Otherwise, the already existing instance is returned. I think this explains the `==` behaviour.

```
String s1="MyString";
String s2=new String("MyString");
s2 = s2.intern();
System.out.println(s1==s2);
```

As a reference, here is what the `String.intern()` documentation says:

```
/**
 * Returns a canonical representation for the string object.
 * <p>
 * A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the
 * class <code>String</code>.
 * <p>
 * When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a
 * string equal to this <code>String</code> object as determined by
 * the {@link #equals(Object)} method, then the string from the pool is
 * returned. Otherwise, this <code>String</code> object is added to the
 * pool and a reference to this <code>String</code> object is returned.
 * <p>
 * It follows that for any two strings <code>s</code> and <code>t</code>,
 * <code>s.intern()&nbsp;==&nbsp;t.intern()</code> is <code>true</code>
 * if and only if <code>s.equals(t)</code> is <code>true</code>.
 * <p>
 * All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are
 * interned. String literals are defined in section 3.10.5 of the
 * <cite>The Java&trade; Language Specification</cite>.
 *
 * @return  a string that has the same contents as this string, but is
 *          guaranteed to be from a pool of unique strings.
 */
public native String intern();
```

Answer (score 6):

In the line `String s2=new String("MyString");` you are creating a **new** instance of `String`, so it will surely won't be the same instance as `s1`.

If you do:

```
System.out.println(s1=="MyString");
```

You will get `true`.

Answer (score 3):

`s2` is NOT a string literal, it was constructed from one when using `new` - but it is not a literal, it is a new object.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you are creating two different objects one is in `Literal Pool` and one is in `Heap`

```
String s1 = "MyString"; //literal pool
String s2 = new String("MyString"); //in heap
s.o.p(s1==s2); // false, because two different instances
s.o.p(s1.equals(s2)); // true, compares the contents of the string.
```

You need to use `equals` instead `==`.
You can push the string objects from heap to String literal pool (or constant pool) by calling `String.intern()`.

Comment: I know that using equals it will match

Answer (score 0):

The String pool is not creating two instances, it is the constructor calls that creates the second `String` instance. From the javadoc of [String(String original)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28java.lang.String%29):

> Initializes a newly created String object so that it represents the same sequence of characters as the argument; in other words, the newly created string is a copy of the argument string. Unless an explicit copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is unnecessary since Strings are immutable.

Consequently, since you are creating a second instance `==` correctly returns `false` (and [equals(Object anObject)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) will return `true`).