# Java: == in print statement gives different answers

Tags: java

```
String a = "abc";
String b = "abc";

System.out.println("Result .... " + a==b); // false
System.out.println(a==b);                  // true
```

1<sup>st</sup> print statement prints `false` and 2<sup>nd</sup> prints `true`, though ideally it has to be `true`. Why is it `false` in 1<sup>st</sup> print statement ?

Comment: You do know not to compare string with `==` right?

Comment: @John3136 I know that very well. Better understand the question scenario.

Comment: Good stuff. Just as soon as I see `string == string` the alarm bells start to go off...

Comment: Why ask same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848089/java-print-statement-only-prints-the-result? Are posted answers not clear? Could you explain what other informations you want to get?

Answer (score 4):

`System.out.println("Result .... " +a==b);` -> the result string will be appended with 'a' and then compares with b so it results false.

Answer (score 4):

**Order of operations:**

```
"Result .... " + a==b
```

is equivalent to

```
("Result .... " +a) == b
```

which will be `false` since the two strings are not the same reference.

The explanation for this is that the `+` addition operator has a *higher* precedence than `==` logical equivalence.

The expression `a == b` is returning `true` in your second statement due to [interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805578/will-two-strings-with-same-content-be-stored-in-the-same-memory-location), in which `a` and `b` actually refer to same string object.

Click [**here**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) for a link to Oracle's table of operator precedence in Java.

Answer (score 2):

1. Forgot checking equality by == in java. In Java this operation checks equality of object link. Additionally it is applicable for checking equality of simple numbers. You should use .equals method

   ```
   String a = "abc";
   String b = new String(a);
   System.out.printLn(a == b);//false
   System.out.println(a.equals(b));//true
   ```
2. Learn about operation order in java

Answer (score 0):

It is because in `"Result .... " +a==b` it first add `"Result .... "` with `a` and then `==` to `b`. If you write like this `"Result .... " +(a==b)`, then it will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

In the first statement, you're comparing `"Result .... " + a` with `b`. In the second one, you're comparing `a` with `b`, hence the difference. Change your first statement as follows:

```
 System.out.println("Result .... " + (a==b));
```

And keep in mind that strings should be compared using the `equals()` method instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println("Result .... " +a==b);`

String `Result` is appended with 'a' and then compares with b so it provides false. `(Result .... a == b)` which is false.

Follow this link to understand [precedence of operators in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) and [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/).

```
Operator + has more precedence than == operator.
```

try adding brackets, you will see the diff. Bracket is evaluated separately.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "abc";
        String b = "abc";

        System.out.println("Result .... " + (a == b)); // false
        System.out.println(a == b); // true}
    }
```

**output**

```
Result .... true
true
```